# If the APU is switched off but the APU bleed is on, will the engine bleed valve close automatically?

Tags: airbus-a320, apu, bleed-air

On he A320 family aircraft, if the APU is switched off but the APU bleed is on, will the engine bleed valve closed by the Bleed Monitoring Computer (BMC)?

This what I understood after going through the APU chapter of the FCOM. Just wanted to confirm because the way I understand it is that the APU bleed valves will not open since it requires a minimum of 8 PSI, so the engine bleed valve should be open.

Comment: No . Here I am not copy pasting the question but this what I thought after going through the APU chapter of the FCOM. Just wanted to know the correct answer for the same because according to me if APU is off even with APU bleed switch ON the APU bleed valves will not open since It requires a minimum of 8 PSI so engine bleed valve should be open according to me

Comment: @SourabhJain, I've tried to include the text from your comment into the question. Please check if I did represent your intention correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the FCOM:

[image: Bleed diagram]

So, the ENG bleed valve closes if:

1. Reverse flow detected
2. ENG 1 starter valve not closed
3. APU bleed valve open
4. Bad things (Overpressure / Overheat / Leak)
5. ENG BLEED switch is off or FIRE pb pushed

So, if APU is not ON, the APU BLEED valve is closed, and then the condition 3 is false. If all the others conditions are also false, then the ENG valve would open.